# Debian 9 is failed after changing LVM configuration on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: debian, lvm

I have the 2 OS which are mentioned it the title.
Debian is installed on LVM disk `/dev/sda5`.

I needed to extend `/var` LVM partition, but I was not able to do this on Debian 9 because there was no free space and I could not unmount `/home` to release free space in order to extend `/var`.

But I booted on Xubuntu and did it there using Logical Volume Manager Utility. I reduced `/home`, extended `/var` and left 25 GB free space.

Now I cannot boot on Debian 9. As I understand Debian can not mount `/home` and `/var` now.

How to update the Debian LVM settings now? I am still able to use `root` user, and Debian sees only `/root` and `/tmp` LVM partitions.

On Xubuntu:

`sudo lvs
  home   desktop-vg -wi-a----- 25.48g

  root   desktop-vg -wi-a----- 18.18g

  swap_1 desktop-vg -wi-a----- 15.94g

  tmp    desktop-vg -wi-a-----  1.14g

  var    desktop-vg -wi-a----- 25.84g`

But I can not remember "desktop-vg" on Debian.

Comment: Can you mount manually? `mkdir /mnt/tmp ; mount /dev/desktop-vg/home /mnt/tmp`

Comment: It works for `tmp`, but does not work for `home` where I changed the size:
 `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/desktop--vg-home`

It does not work on Xubuntu too. How can I repair it?

Comment: Unfortunately it lokks like you have destroyed that LV. The question is: What has your tool done? You may have at look at the backups in `/etc/lvm` (on both distros). If you are lucky then they contain the information where the LV data was before the change. It may be easiest to restore the backup before your change and make the changes again, manually.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I used `system-config-lvm 1.1.18 ` GUI utility. I see I get the big problem. I have some files in `/etc/lvm/archive` and `/etc/lvm/backup`.
Is there a short way to restore it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68268/discussion-between-artu-and-hauke-laging).

Answer (score 0):

Find the backup file for the respective volume group in `/etc/lvm/archive` (based on its modification date and the `created before ...` comment). It may be a good idea to copy all these files elsewhere first.

Then run

```
vgcfgrestore -f /etc/lvm/archive/$correct_file
```

After you have reached the old state you should make the changes manually instead of with that tool (with `lvreduce --resizefs`).